# how to display paypal stored credit card details for existing or repeat customer in my website?

Tags: php, paypal, credit-card

I am storing credit card details on paypal server and return below code.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => CARD-817429813C079815KKXSTCWI
    [state] => ok
    [payer_id] => user12345
    [type] => visa
    [number] => xxxxxxxxxxxx0331
    [expire_month] => 11
    [expire_year] => 2018
    [first_name] => Joe1
    [last_name] => Shopper1
    [valid_until] => 2018-08-31T00:00:00Z
    [create_time] => 2015-09-01T05:02:17Z
    [update_time] => 2015-09-01T05:02:17Z
    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/CARD-817429813C079815KKXSTCWI
                    [rel] => self
                    [method] => GET
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/CARD-817429813C079815KKXSTCWI
                    [rel] => delete
                    [method] => DELETE
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/CARD-817429813C079815KKXSTCWI
                    [rel] => patch
                    [method] => PATCH
                )

        )

)
```

.

i have id as `credit_card_id and payer_id`
How to achieve below functionality ?

if exist or repeat customer purchase a product next time,just automatically fill credit card details from `paypal` so save time for customer

**how to display customer credit card details in my website which already stored in `paypal` server ?**

please guide me
MY TESTING PHP and HTML data below

```
<style>
.creditcard .float1 { float:left; }
</style>
<?php 
$clientId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        $ipnexec = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"); // test url

        curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
        curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
        //curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        //curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //curl_setopt($ipnexec, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        $ipnresult = curl_exec($ipnexec);
            $result = json_decode($ipnresult);
        echo "<pre>";
        $access_token = $result->access_token;
        //print_r($result->access_token);
        $token_type = $result->token_type;  
        curl_close($ipnexec);


// phase 2 for credit card payment

$scope = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card";
$expire_month = 11;
$expire_year = 2018;
$first_name = "joe1";
$last_name = "shopper1";
$method = "storecreditcard";
$number = 4446283280247004;
$type = "visa";
$payer_id="manthan228@gmail.com";
$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 1);
$data = '
 {
 "payer_id":"user12345",
 "type":"visa",
 "number":"4417119669820331",
 "expire_month":"11",
 "expire_year":"2018",
 "first_name":"Joe1",
 "last_name":"Shopper1"
}
';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$scope);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
    print_r($json);
}
curl_close($ch);

/**************************** phase 3 ***********************************/
$ch = curl_init();

$data = '{
  "intent":"sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card_token":{
          "credit_card_id":"'.$json->id.'",
          "payer_id":"user12345"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD"
      },
      "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}
';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token));

$result = curl_exec($ch);


if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json);
}



?>


<div class="creditcard" style="height:400px;width:400px; padding:2px;border:3px solid blue">
<p>card number</p>

<div style="border:1px solid grey;padding:2px 5px">
<?php echo $json->id ?>
</div>

<div>
<p>Name on card</p>
<div style="border:1px solid grey;padding:5px 5px">
<?php echo $json->first_name." ".$json->first_name ?>
</div>
<div class="float1">
<span>Expiry Month</span>
<span style="border:1px solid grey; padding:2px 5px;width:100px;padding:4px;"><?php echo $json->expire_month ?> </span>
</div>
<div class="float1">
<span>Expiry Year</span>
<span  style="border:1px solid grey;width:100px; padding:4px;"><?php echo $json->expire_year ?></span>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you save the data's in database ?

Comment: Where's is your html or php code?

Comment: I really *really* don't recommend doing this...

Comment: can i save id as credit_card_id in my database ?

Comment: i have added my curl php and html data

Comment: should i save response id as credit_card_id in my database table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: as per comments, since what you're trying to achieve is to use the saved CC, you can use the `id` provided by Paypal in the `vault/credit-card` call as the `credit_card_id` of the `payment` calls. Here is Paypal payments overview for Vault: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/#use-a-stored-credit-card

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER

You shouldn't save credit card data on your server, too many security and privacy issues.

You may want to create a BillingAgreement instead. Basically, paypal will store CC data for the user and asks him permission to capture future payments on your site without inserting all the data. You will then have a Billing Agreement ID that you can use for later payments. See here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/

Comment: i am storing storing credit card data on paypal server,not my server and question is when same customer purchase a product so how to display stored customer credit card data on payment section in my website ?

Comment: The question is then not clear. Paypal doesn't return the full CC data for obvious security reasons. You will only have the last four digits and some other data (expiration date, holder name, ...). As a user, I prefer that my payment data is encrypted and that noone can access it even if someone hacks my account. Most of the ecommerce sites, Amazon included, only show the last four digits to the user. If you want to have the full CC number echoed to the user, you will have to save it when the user inserts it, but the user will have to be informed for privacy reasons.

Comment: for security reason,if i stored credit card data on paypal,paypal returns credit card reference token [id] => CARD-817429813C079815KKXSTCWI ,if i store this id in my database not credit card data for same customer to paypal then credit token as [id] => CARD-817429813C079815KKXSTCWI,total and currency pass to paypal so this id pass on paypal server and point out to credit card data so this id refers credit card data on paypal server.

Comment: so can i store reference paypal token as  [id] => CARD-817429813C079815KKXSTCWI in my database ? see above code

Comment: Exactly, you can use that token to use your credit card, as explained here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/#use-a-stored-credit-card - original answer updated.

Comment: paypal return  [number] => xxxxxxxxxxxx0331
    [expire_month] => 11
    [expire_year] => 2018
    [first_name] => Joe1
    [last_name] => Shopper1  can i save this my database because paypal return this code after stored credit card in paypal server ?

Comment: ok i got it, it does not require to store response CC data in my database because i can fetch CC data from paypal through this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-stored-credit-card using id as credit_card_id

Comment: If I want update stored CC detail or delete, what can I do?